# In the report class, can the abstract go on the title page?

Tags: abstract, report

In the standard LaTeX report class, must the abstract go on a different page than the title, or is that something which may be avoided (i.e. all on a single page)? If so, how can I get the abstract to go on the title page?

Comment: It can be avoided.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Ok, Edited to ask _how_...

Comment: Easiest solution is to not use \maketitle and format the title page yourself.  Copy and modify the report.cls code (tex\latex\base folder).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `notitlepage` document option. Then `\maketitle` doesn't create a page of its own.